# Do we want to handle questions about Backdrop?

Tags: discussion, questions

Should Drupal Answers be welcoming to questions about [Backdrop CMS](https://backdropcms.org/).  From their [docs](https://backdropcms.org/leadership):

> Backdrop CMS started its existence as an offshoot or fork of Drupal.
>   Although Backdrop originates from a common codebase with Drupal, its
>   philosophy and organization are distinct. Backdrop practices a policy
>   of focused releases, taking into account the feedback from the
>   community. The overall direction is guided by the Backdrop Project
>   Management Committee (PMC), modeled off of the Apache project.

Unlike [Pressflow](http://www.pressflow.org/), Backdrop has progressed to a point where it isn't 100% API compatible with Drupal anymore.

So, do we want to handle Backdrop questions here?

Comment: I would really like to get answers from people who have **actually deployed Backdrop sites**.  Also, the fork caused quite a stir in the community, and I want to avoid that here.  My main concern is whether allowing Backdrop question here would mean that we have two distinct userbases, which would potentially mean DA being two sites in one.

Answer (score 11):

I vote for not supporting Backdrop questions in here just because at some point Backdrop will very fairly different from Drupal 7. Since their philosophy and organisation are distinct, it is going to be a different CMS. We currently have a major different between Drupal 8 and Drupal 7 adding Backdrop support into [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) is technically supporting a third CMS.

Assuming that Backdrop gets mature enough that have another major version is going to be a fourth CMS to handle at the same time.

Comment: I have to agree with this - the site isn't called "Drupal and Backdrop Answers", after all. If we dilute the expertise here down to two different disciplines, that are growing further and further apart all the time, by design, then everyone loses. Let's keep Drupal Answers for Drupal, and lend our support to any effort the Backdrop guys want to make towards starting their own Stack Exchange site